# Using values from slider in javascript DataTables calculations

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I've got a nested `DataTable` in my shiny app that is made from the data below. There are two sliders that I have which make up a percentage of 100. If one slider is 50 the other sider is 50. These two numbers from the two sliders help make up the `Spot:30(%)` and the `Spot:15(%)` columns of the child table.

There is another column, `Mix(%)`, where the user is able to go in and edit the numbers. When the user edits this column the numbers in the `Spot:30(%)` and the `Spot:15(%)` columns are suppose to be updated accordingly.

The equations are:

`Spot:30(%) = (Mix(%) * slider_value1)/100`

`Spot:15(%) = (Mix(%) * slider_value2)/100`

Is there a way to use slider values from the Shiny app in the `JS callback` script to update the `Spot:30(%)` and the `Spot:15(%)` columns when the `Mix(%)` column is edited by the user??

I've attempted to try a solution like this one, [example1](https://www.r-bloggers.com/edit-datatables-in-r-shiny-app/), as well as trying to follow this, [communicating with shiny via javascript](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html), but can't seem to wrap my head around this.

**Data**

```
Parent
structure(list(Market = c("ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY"
), `Gross CPP` = c("$0", "$0"), `Gross CPM` = c("$0", "$0"), 
    `Historical Composite Gross CPP` = c("$0", "$0"), `Historical Composite Gross CPM` = c("$0", 
    "$0")), .Names = c("Market", "Gross CPP", "Gross CPM", "Historical Composite Gross CPP", 
"Historical Composite Gross CPM"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

Child
structure(list(Market = c("ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", 
"ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", 
"ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", 
"ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", 
"ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", 
"ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", 
"ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", 
"ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", 
"ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY"), Daypart = c("Daytime", "Early Fringe", 
"Early Morning", "Early News", "Late Fringe", "Late News", "Prime Access", 
"Prime Time", "tv_2", "tv_cross_screen", "Daytime", "Early Fringe", 
"Early Morning", "Early News", "Late Fringe", "Late News", "Prime Access", 
"Prime Time", "tv_2", "tv_cross_screen"), `Mix (%)` = c(15, 10, 
15, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 0, 0, 15, 10, 15, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 0, 
0), `Spot:30 (%)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Spot:15 (%)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Gross CPP ($)` = c(18, 
18, 16, 23, 24, 40, 26, 44, 0, 0, 77, 71, 61, 78, 109, 145, 93, 
213, 0, 0), `Gross CPM ($)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 13, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 13), `Historical Override CPP ($)` = c(18, 
18, 16, 23, 24, 40, 26, 44, 0, 0, 77, 71, 61, 78, 109, 145, 93, 
213, 0, 0), `Historical Override CPM ($)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 23, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 13)), .Names = c("Market", 
"Daypart", "Mix (%)", "Spot:30 (%)", "Spot:15 (%)", "Gross CPP ($)", 
"Gross CPM ($)", "Historical Override CPP ($)", "Historical Override CPM ($)"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

**EDIT**

For some reason when I move the slider the Shiny Server observes the event and prints out the new slider value, but that new slider value doesn't get passed to the JS callback which in turn doesn't update the DataTable. The data table stays at the `var slider = 50` and doesn't update.

**Code**

```
# The datatable callback
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
callback_js = JS(
  "var tv_spots30 = 50;",
  "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('sliderValue1', function(value1){",
  "  tv_spots30 = value1;",
  "  $('#' + children[0]).DataTable().draw()",
  "  $('#' + children[1]).DataTable().draw();",
  "});",
  "var spots15 = 50;",
  "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('sliderValue2', function(value2){",
  "  spots15 = value2;",
  "  $('#' + children[0]).DataTable().draw();",
  "  $('#' + children[1]).DataTable().draw();",
  "});",
  "function onUpdate(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {};",
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(var i=0; i < nrows; ++i){",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// make the table header of the nested table",
  "var format = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d != null){",
  "    var html = ",
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead><tfoot><tr>'",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th></th>';",
  "    }",
  "    return html + '</tr></tfoot></table>';",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// row callback to style the rows of the child tables",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lightblue');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// header callback to style the header of the child tables",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid green',",
  "    'color': 'black',",
  "    'background-color': 'white'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// make the datatable",
  "var format_datatable = function(d, childId, rowIdx){",
  "  // footer callback to display the totals",
  "  // and update the parent row",
  "  var footerCallback = function(tfoot, data, start, end, display){",
  "    $('th', tfoot).css('background-color', '#F5F2F2');",
  "    var api = this.api();",
  "    var col_mix = api.column(2).data();",
  "    for(let i = 0; i < col_mix.length; i++){",
  "      api.cell(i,3).data(parseFloat(col_mix[i])*tv_spots30/100);",
  "      api.cell(i,4).data(parseFloat(col_mix[i])*spots15/100);",
  "    }",
  "    api.columns().eq(0).each(function(index){",
  "      if(index == 0) return $(api.column(index).footer()).html('Mix Total');",
  "      var coldata = api.column(index).data();",
  "      var total = coldata",
  "          .reduce(function(a, b){return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)}, 0);",
  "      if(index == 3 || index == 4 ||index == 5 || index == 6 || index==7 || index==8) {",
  "        $(api.column(index).footer()).html('');",
  "      } else {",
  "        $(api.column(index).footer()).html(total);",
  "      }",
  "      if(total == 100) {",
  "        $(api.column(index).footer()).css({'color': 'green'});",
  "      } else {",
  "        $(api.column(index).footer()).css({'color': 'red'});",
  "      }",
  "    })",
  "  // update the parent row",
  "    var col_share = api.column(2).data();",
  "    var col_CPP = api.column(5).data();",
  "    var col_CPM = api.column(6).data();",
  "    var col_Historical_CPP = api.column(7).data();",
  "    var col_Historical_CPM = api.column(8).data();",
  "    var CPP = 0, CPM = 0, Historical_CPP = 0, Historical_CPM = 0;",
  "    for(var i = 0; i < col_share.length; i++){",
  "      CPP += (parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_CPP[i]).toFixed(2));",
  "      CPM += (parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_CPM[i]).toFixed(2));",
  "      Historical_CPP += (parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_Historical_CPP[i]).toFixed(2));",
  "      Historical_CPM += (parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_Historical_CPM[i]).toFixed(2));",
  "    }",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+2).data((CPP/100).toFixed(2));",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+3).data((CPM/100).toFixed(2));",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+4).data((Historical_CPP/100).toFixed(2));",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+5).data((Historical_CPM/100).toFixed(2));",
  "  }",
  "  var dataset = [];",
  "  var n = d.length - 1;",
  "  for(var i = 0; i < d[n].length; i++){",
  "    var datarow = $.map(d[n][i], function (value, index) {",
  "      return [value];",
  "    });",
  "    dataset.push(datarow);",
  "  }",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  if (Object.keys(d[n][0]).indexOf('_details') === -1) {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "                 'data': dataset,",
  "                 'autoWidth': true,",
  "                 'deferRender': true,",
  "                 'info': false,",
  "                 'lengthChange': false,",
  "                 'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "                 'order': [],",
  "                 'paging': true,",
  "                 'scrollX': false,",
  "                 'scrollY': false,",
  "                 'searching': false,",
  "                 'sortClasses': false,",
  "                 'pageLength': 50,",
  "                 'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "                 'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "                 'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
  "                 'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "               });",
  "  } else {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "            'data': dataset,",
  "            'autoWidth': true,",
  "            'deferRender': true,",
  "            'info': false,",
  "            'lengthChange': false,",
  "            'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "            'order': [],",
  "            'paging': true,",
  "            'scrollX': false,",
  "            'scrollY': false,",
  "            'searching': false,",
  "            'sortClasses': false,",
  "            'pageLength': 50,",
  "            'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "            'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "            'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
  "            'columnDefs': [",
  "              {targets: -1, visible: false},",
  "              {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},",
  "              {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "             ]",
  "          }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }",
  "  subtable.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "    onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "    inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "    columns: [2, 7, 8],",
  "    confirmationButton: {",
  "      confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "      cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// display the child table on click",
  "var children = [];", # array to store the id's of the already created child tables
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "    if(children.indexOf(childId) === -1){", # this child table has not been created yet
  "      children.push(childId);",
  "      row.child(format(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "      format_datatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
  "    }else{",
  "      row.child(true);",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});")

# Module to create the nested structure of the table
NestedData <- function(dat, children){
  stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
  g <- function(d){
    if(is.data.frame(d)){
      purrr::transpose(d)
    }else{
      purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
    }
  }
  subdats <- lapply(children, g)
  oplus <- sapply(subdats, function(x) if(length(x)) "&oplus;" else "")
  cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}


# shiny
    # Bind the market level and mix breakout data together for the final table
    market_mix_table <- reactive({
      markets <- market_costings_gross_net()
      mix_breakout <- mix_breakout_digital_elements()
      # Make the dataframe
      # This must be met length(children) == nrow(dat)
      Dat <- NestedData(
        dat = markets,
        children = split(mix_breakout, mix_breakout$Market)
      )
      return(Dat)
    })

    # Render the table
    output$daypartTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      Server = FALSE
      # Whether to show row names (set TRUE or FALSE)
      rowNames <- FALSE
      colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)
      # The data
      Dat <- market_mix_table()
      # Table
      table <- DT::datatable(
        Dat,
        callback = callback_js,
        rownames = rowNames,
        escape = -colIdx-1,
        style = "bootstrap4",
          options = list(
            lengthMenu = list(
              c(-1, 10, 20),
              c("All", 10, 20)
            ),
            columnDefs = list(
              list(width = '30px'),
              list(width = '100px', targets = 1),
              list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx),
              list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = colIdx),
              list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
            )
          )
        )
      # Some faancy Java magic
      path <- getwd()
      # Call the html tools deps (js & css files in this directory)
      dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
        "CellEdit", "1.0.19", path,
        script = "dataTables.cellEdit.js", stylesheet = "dataTables.cellEdit.css")
      table$dependencies <- c(table$dependencies, list(dep))
      # server = FALSE
      return(table)
    })

observeEvent(input[["tv_spots30"]], {
  print("30%")
  print(input[["tv_spots30"]])
  session$sendCustomMessage("sliderValue1", input[["tv_spots30"]])
})

observeEvent(input[["spots15"]], {
  print("15%")
  print(input[["spots15"]])
  session$sendCustomMessage("sliderValue2", input[["spots15"]])
})

# ui
          sliderInput("tv_spots30",
                      "Spots 30 (%):",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100,
                      value = 50,
                      step = 5
          ),
          sliderInput("spots15",
                      "Spots 15 (%):",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100,
                      value = 50,
                      step = 5
          ),
```

Comment: I'm trying. I understand that `slider_value1 + slider_value2 = 100`, so you need only one slider, no?

Comment: thanks so much for your willing to help me out in all of this. So technically the first slider is a percentage of the users `Spot:30(%)` and the second slider is their percentage of `Spot:15(%)`. If my `Mix(%)` column is 15, `Spot:30(%)` slider is 50, and `Spot:15(%)` slider is 40. Then the `Spot:30(%)` column equals 50% of 15 and the `Spot:15(%)` column is 40% of 15. Does that make more sense??

Comment: So you just mean the two slider values are not related to each other?

Comment: yea, basically. Both are related to the `Mix(%)` column, but not to one another.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I achieved.

At the beginning of the callback:

```
  "var slider = 50;",
  "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('sliderValue', function(value){",
  "  slider = value;",
  "  $('#' + children[0]).DataTable().draw();",
  "  $('#' + children[1]).DataTable().draw();",
  "});",
```

In server:

```
  observeEvent(input[["slider"]], {
    session$sendCustomMessage("sliderValue", input[["slider"]])
  })
```

And in the footer callback:

```
  "    var col_mix = api.column(2).data();",
  "    for(let i = 0; i < col_mix.length; i++){",
  "      api.cell(i,3).data(parseFloat(col_mix[i])*slider/100);",
  "      api.cell(i,4).data(parseFloat(col_mix[i])*(100-slider)/100);",
  "    }",
```

Full code:

```
library(DT)

df_children <- structure(
  list(
    Market = c("ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY"), 
    Daypart = c("Daytime", "Early Fringe", "Early Morning", "Early News", "Late Fringe", "Late News", "Prime Access", "Prime Time", "tv_2", "tv_cross_screen", "Daytime", "Early Fringe", "Early Morning", "Early News", "Late Fringe", "Late News", "Prime Access", "Prime Time", "tv_2", "tv_cross_screen"), 
    `Mix (%)` = c(15, 10, 15, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 0, 0, 15, 10, 15, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 0, 0), 
    `Spot:30 (%)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `Spot:15 (%)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `Gross CPP ($)` = c(18, 18, 16, 23, 24, 40, 26, 44, 0, 0, 77, 71, 61, 78, 109, 145, 93, 213, 0, 0), 
    `Gross CPM ($)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 13), 
    `Historical Override CPP ($)` = c(18, 18, 16, 23, 24, 40, 26, 44, 0, 0, 77, 71, 61, 78, 109, 145, 93, 213, 0, 0), 
    `Historical Override CPM ($)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 13)
  ), 
  .Names = c("Market", "Daypart", "Mix (%)", "Spot:30 (%)", "Spot:15 (%)", "Gross CPP ($)", "Gross CPM ($)", "Historical Override CPP ($)", "Historical Override CPM ($)"), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -20L)
)

df_parent <- structure(
  list(
    Market = c("ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY"), 
    `Gross CPP` = c("$0", "$0"), 
    `Gross CPM` = c("$0", "$0"), 
    `Historical Composite Gross CPP` = c("$0", "$0"), 
    `Historical Composite Gross CPM` = c("$0", "$0")
  ), 
  .Names = c("Market", "Gross CPP", "Gross CPM", "Historical Composite Gross CPP", "Historical Composite Gross CPM"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -2L), 
  class = "data.frame")

# function to make the required dataframe
NestedData <- function(dat, children){
  stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
  g <- function(d){
    if(is.data.frame(d)){
      purrr::transpose(d)
    }else{
      purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
    }
  }
  subdats <- lapply(children, g)
  oplus <- sapply(subdats, function(x) if(length(x)) "&oplus;" else "")
  cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

# make the required dataframe
# one must have: length(children) == nrow(dat)
Dat <- NestedData(
  dat = df_parent,
  children = split(df_children, df_children$Market)
)

## whether to show row names (set TRUE or FALSE)
rowNames <- FALSE
colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)

## make the callback
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
callback = JS(
  "var slider = 50;",
  "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('sliderValue', function(value){",
  "  slider = value;",
  "  $('#' + children[0]).DataTable().draw();",
  "  $('#' + children[1]).DataTable().draw();",
  "});",
  "function onUpdate(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {};",
  "table.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "  onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "  inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "  confirmationButton: {",
  "    confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "    cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "  }",
  "});",
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(var i=0; i < nrows; ++i){",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// make the table header of the nested table",
  "var format = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d != null){",
  "    var html = ", 
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead><tfoot><tr>'",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th></th>';",
  "    }",
  "    return html + '</tr></tfoot></table>';",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// row callback to style the rows of the child tables",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#E6FF99');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDFF75');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// header callback to style the header of the child tables",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',", 
  "    'color': 'indigo',",
  "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// make the datatable",
  "var format_datatable = function(d, childId, rowIdx){",
  "  // footer callback to display the totals",
  "  // and update the parent row",
  "  var footerCallback = function(tfoot, data, start, end, display){",
  "    $('th', tfoot).css('background-color', '#F5F2F2');",
  "    var api = this.api();",
  "    var col_mix = api.column(2).data();",
  "    for(let i = 0; i < col_mix.length; i++){",
  "      api.cell(i,3).data(parseFloat(col_mix[i])*slider/100);",
  "      api.cell(i,4).data(parseFloat(col_mix[i])*(100-slider)/100);",
  "    }",
  "    api.columns().eq(0).each(function(index){",
  "      if(index == 0) return $(api.column(index).footer()).html('Mix Total');",
  "      var coldata = api.column(index).data();",
  "      var total = coldata",
  "          .reduce(function(a, b){return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)}, 0);",
  "      if(index == 3 || index == 4 ||index == 5 || index == 6 || index==7 || index==8) {",
  "        $(api.column(index).footer()).html('');",
  "      } else {",
  "        $(api.column(index).footer()).html(total);",
  "      }",
  "      if(total == 100) {",
  "        $(api.column(index).footer()).css({'color': 'green'});",
  "      } else {",
  "        $(api.column(index).footer()).css({'color': 'red'});",
  "      }",
  "    })",
  "  // update the parent row",
  "    var col_share = api.column(2).data();",
  "    var col_CPP = api.column(5).data();",
  "    var col_CPM = api.column(6).data();",
  "    var col_Historical_CPP = api.column(7).data();",
  "    var col_Historical_CPM = api.column(8).data();",
  "    var CPP = 0, CPM = 0, Historical_CPP = 0, Historical_CPM = 0;",
  "    for(var i = 0; i < col_share.length; i++){",
  "      CPP += (parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_CPP[i]).toFixed(2));",
  "      CPM += (parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_CPM[i]).toFixed(2));",
  "      Historical_CPP += (parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_Historical_CPP[i]).toFixed(2));",
  "      Historical_CPM += (parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_Historical_CPM[i]).toFixed(2));",
  "    }",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+2).data((CPP/100).toFixed(2));",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+3).data((CPM/100).toFixed(2));",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+4).data((Historical_CPP/100).toFixed(2));",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+5).data((Historical_CPM/100).toFixed(2));",
  "  }",
  "  var dataset = [];",
  "  var n = d.length - 1;",
  "  for(var i = 0; i < d[n].length; i++){",
  "    var datarow = $.map(d[n][i], function (value, index) {",
  "      return [value];",
  "    });",
  "    dataset.push(datarow);",
  "  }",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  if (Object.keys(d[n][0]).indexOf('_details') === -1) {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "                 'data': dataset,",
  "                 'autoWidth': true,",
  "                 'deferRender': true,",
  "                 'info': false,",
  "                 'lengthChange': false,",
  "                 'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "                 'order': [],",
  "                 'paging': false,",
  "                 'scrollX': false,",
  "                 'scrollY': false,",
  "                 'searching': false,",
  "                 'sortClasses': false,",
  "                 'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "                 'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "                 'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
  "                 'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "               });",
  "  } else {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "            'data': dataset,",
  "            'autoWidth': true,",
  "            'deferRender': true,",
  "            'info': false,",
  "            'lengthChange': false,",
  "            'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "            'order': [],",
  "            'paging': false,",
  "            'scrollX': false,",
  "            'scrollY': false,",
  "            'searching': false,",
  "            'sortClasses': false,",
  "            'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "            'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "            'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
  "            'columnDefs': [", 
  "              {targets: -1, visible: false},", 
  "              {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},", 
  "              {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "             ]",
  "          }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }",
  "  subtable.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "    onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "    inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "    confirmationButton: {",
  "      confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "      cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// display the child table on click",
  "var children = [];", # array to store the id's of the already created child tables
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "    if(children.indexOf(childId) === -1){", # this child table has not been created yet
  "      children.push(childId);",
  "      row.child(format(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "      format_datatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
  "    }else{",
  "      row.child(true);",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});")

## the datatable
dtable <- datatable(
  Dat, callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx),
      list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = colIdx),
      list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
    )
  )
)
path <- "~/Work/R/DT" # folder containing the files dataTables.cellEdit.js
                      # and dataTables.cellEdit.css
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "CellEdit", "1.0.19", path, 
  script = "dataTables.cellEdit.js", stylesheet = "dataTables.cellEdit.css")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))

# Shiny ####
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      sliderInput("slider", "Percentage", min = 0, max = 100, value = 50, step = 1)
    ),
    column(
      width = 8, 
      DTOutput("tbl")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["tbl"]] <- renderDT(dtable)

  observeEvent(input[["slider"]], {
    session$sendCustomMessage("sliderValue", input[["slider"]])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I followed your example, adding in my other second slider. The Shiny Server observes the event when I move the slider, but the new slider value doesn't get passed to the JS callback to update the table. See my edited code up in my post

Comment: When I go to print out `session$sendCustomMessage("sliderValue1", input$tv_spots30)` it prints `NULL`. Is that why its not sending the updated slider value to the JS callback?

Comment: @TimothyMcwilliams You mean `print(session$sendCustomMessage(......` ? That should print nothing. You deleted a comment in which you said that your datatable is rerendered when you change the slider values. This is likely the problem.

Comment: I fixed that issue, however my slider value is still being passed to my `JS callback`. The value is static at the `var tv_spots30 = 50;` and is never updated when I move the slider.

Comment: I actually didn't fix the rendering problem at all. I thought I did, but the table still renders each time I move the slider. I do use the slider value in other reactive methods to calculate some numbers on the back end which is why it renders when I change the slider. Any idea of how to get around that? Like anything on the JS side where it updates again and again?

Comment: something like `"var slider = 100;",`
  `"setInterval(function(){",`
  `"    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('sliderValue1', function(value){",`
  ` "    slider = value;",`
  `"    console.log(slider);",`
  ` "    });",`
  ` "}, 2000);",`

Comment: @TimothyMcwilliams Why does the table render when you move the slider? This looks highly problematic, that means all edits are reseted each time you move the slider.

Comment: The sliders should only be used once by the user. They set the sliders values, those values get used to calculate the back end `Gross CPP` and `Gross CPM` columns, and then they get to edit the table.

Comment: I've worked on a solution where I wrap all of the reactive methods in `isolate()` and then make them also have a dependency on an action button. However, the slider values in the table take on the default values in the `JS callback` until I move the sliders again

Comment: is there anyway to move the sliders then send those values to the `JS callback` and have those render in the table? Instead of having a default value in the `JS callback` and that value only updating when you move the slider?